# SVM on BERT-Embeddings with very small dataset does not converge

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, embeddings, text-classification, transformer

I am trying to reproduce the results from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.13138.pdf) where they use a linear SVM on top of BERT-Embeddings for text-classification. They use the average of the token-embeddings which results in a 768 dimensional vector for each sample.

As this is active-learning, the number of samples used is very small (between 40 and 500).

So: `nb_samples < nb_features`.

I thought that a SVM converges most of the times (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453793/does-svm-always-converge)), and surely in the cases where `nb_samples < nb_features`. However, this is not the case, even with only 40 samples, the SVM (LinearSVC from sklearn) does not converge.

I am quite sure my embeddings are somehow meaningful, they look also ok (values between between -1 and 1) no need for normalization etc.

**What could be my problem?**

I tried `dual=True and dual=False, increasing max_iter to 10000` etc.